# Angular Router: Get route config that matched the current route

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have the following route configuration in my Angular project:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'a/:id', loadChildren: './a/a.module#AModule', data: {a: a}},
  { path: 'b/:id',  loadChildren: './b/b.module#BModule', data: {a: b}}
];
```

Now I can get my route configuration like this:

```
this.router.config //outputs the above array
```

The `this.router.url` shows `a`, but how would I correctly identify the correct `Route` since the configuration has the unresolved path and the router holds the resolved path.

The reason I want to do that is to access the `data` in the `app.component` where my `router-outlet` is and not in the component itself (the angular documentation says that the `data` object is only accessible to the route component itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using this code:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
        console.log(event.state.root.firstChild.data['a']);
     }
});
```

Comment: RoutesRecognized occurs before Guard checks so the navigation could still fail. Thus, this is probably not a good general solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Router.state` to get original `Route` config.

Angular router represents current route as a hierarchical route tree due to `children`, thus you need to traverse it to get deepest child which is usually what you're looking for.

Can be done in following way:

```
let currentRoute = this.router.routerState.root;
while (currentRoute.firstChild) {
    currentRoute = currentRoute.firstChild;
}
console.log(currentRoute.routeConfig); // returns `Route` object
```

In order to react to changes this should be inside `this.router.events.subscribe(...)`.

Comment: It working thank you!
Just to complement the answer, in order to react to route changes and wait for the route to be loaded, just added this pipe:

this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((e: any) => e instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(...)

Comment: Is this still valid for Angular 15? The only properties I see on NavigationEnd are: id
url
urlAfterRedirects

Answer (score 1):

This config can be accessed without the event, from onInit root for example (but can be used in the subscription body too):

```
const config = !!this.activatedRoute.snapshot.root.firstChild.children.length
      ? this.activatedRoute.snapshot.root.firstChild.firstChild.data
      : this.activatedRoute.snapshot.root.firstChild.data;
this.hideHeader = config['hideHeader'] ?? false;
```

The children length check is for the two level config:

```
  RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
      path: 'login',
      component: WelcomePageComponent,
      data: {
        hideHeader: true,
      },
    },
    {
      path: '',
      canActivateChild: [AuthGuard, ACLGuard],
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          redirectTo: 'wizard',
          pathMatch: 'full',
        },
        {
          path: 'wizard',
          data: {
            hideHeader: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use activate output of router-outlet inside your app component

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

it gives you the laoded component

in your app.component.ts

```
onActivate(event : any) {
   console.log(event);
}
```

example:
[image]

Comment: I just want to access the `data` not the whole component. I don't need to access the component.

Answer (score 0):

I would resolve this issue splitting up the lazy loading route making it simpler.
Root Routing:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'a', loadChildren: './a/a.module#AModule'},
  { path: 'b',  loadChildren: './b/b.module#BModule'}
];
```

Module A routing:

```
export const aModuleRoutes: Routes = [
             { path: 'item/:id', component: YourComponent, data: {a: a}}  
];
```

Module B routing:

```
export const bModuleRoutes: Routes = [
             { path: 'item/:id', component: YourComponent, data: {a: b}}  
];
```

Here you have an individual route for each module and you can play with the individual module route.
Happy coding

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help me accessing the `data`? Furthermore, I'd like to keep the lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

IMO to get routeConfig you need ActivationEnd event of router events. I have searched for param in path to compare it by this way:

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
if (event instanceof ActivationEnd) {
  const segmentArr = event.snapshot.routeConfig.path.split('/'); // there will be what you need
  const lastSegment = segmentArr.pop();
  // if the segment is not a param
  if (lastSegment.includes(':')) {
   // this is ":someparam" segment
  }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to access the route data inside your component is by injecting the `ActivatedRoute` and grab it from the snapshot. An example:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  private data: { a: any }; 

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
    
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = this.route.snapshot.data;
  }
}
```